# Change default icon of buttons on toolbar of CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

How do I can change the default icon of button on toolbar of CKEditor my my owns?

Thanks.

Comment: what button do you want to replace ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to modify one of the default icons (not a plugin's) you can modify `skins\[name of your skin]\icons.png` (suggested [here](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=22359))

Answer (score 1):

Look into plugins folder - source code is there with links to images, just replace those with yours.

Comment: That works of course, but then on upgrading CKeditor in the future, you'll have to remember which files you overwrote.. :/